# How to compare a string from a list object with a another normal string

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a List object I want to check all the duplicate names while saving in to db below is my code but its not working :

```
List<ChartOfAccount> checkDuplicateDetails = accountTypeRepository.checkDuplicateDetails();
    for (ChartOfAccount chartOfAccDuplicate: checkDuplicateDetails) {   
      if(chartOfAccDuplicate.getAccountName().equals("hello123")){
        System.out.println("found duplicate");
      }else {               
        chartOfAccRepository.save(chartOfAccount);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you check for the account name "hello123"?

Comment: i want to check the existing account name if already hello123 is exist or not in db

Comment: Then execute a database query counting accounts with name "hello123". You really don't want to load all your database table in memory just to find one account.

Comment: use LinkedHashSet  instead of List ,  and  override equals and hashcode methods in ChartOfAccount.

Comment: @gajju_15 can u plz give me some sample code

Comment: is printing found duplicate is mandatory in your case? If not you can make the account name a key and reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1. Your chartOfAccDuplicate.getAccountName() method is not returning a **string** litereal
2. or you have to use chartOfAccDuplicate.getAccountName().**equalsIgnoreCase**("hello123")